# Projective limit of system sets compatible maps $\phi : \{x_1, \dots, x_n \} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, limits-colimits

This question is about the projective limit of the following system:

- Let $I$ be the poset of finite subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ 
  partially ordered by inclusion.
- Let $S_U$ be the set of injective maps $\phi : U \hookrightarrow \mathbb{Z}$.
- For $U \subseteq V$, let 
  $f_{VU} \ : \ S_V \longrightarrow S_U \ : \ \phi \longmapsto \phi|_U$

I have to show that the projective limit 
$\varprojlim_{W \in I} S_W \ = \ \emptyset$.
How can I do this?

---

**My own thoughts**

It is easy to show that the definitions above give rise to a projective system.
According to [the notes I work with](http://websites.math.leidenuniv.nl/algebra/GSchemes.pdf) the projective limit is of the system above is:
$$
\left\{ (\phi_W)_{W \in I} :
\forall (U, V \text{ s.t. } U \subseteq V),
\ f_{VU}(\phi_V) = \phi_U 
\right\}
$$

Let's look at $(\phi_W)_{W\in I} \in \varprojlim_{W \in I} S_W $.
For any finite $U,V \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ the maps
$\phi_U$ and $\phi_V$ have to agree on $U \cap V$.
This makes me think that the $(\phi_W)_W$ corresponds with a map 
$\phi : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$. 
As a matter of fact, thanks to the compatibility constraints we could just define:
$$
\phi \ : \ \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z} 
\ : \ x \longmapsto \phi_{\{x\}}(x)
$$ 
This makes me think that the projective limit we consider is the set of injective maps 
$\phi : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$.
Since $\mathbb{R}$ isn't countable such maps don't exist.

---

What does actually justify the last thought? I thought of proving the universal property of $\{ \phi : \mathbb{R} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{Z} \}$ with maps
$$
f_i \ : \ \{ \phi : \mathbb{R} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{Z} \} 
\ \longrightarrow  \ \varprojlim_{W \in I} S_W 
\ : \ \phi  \ \longmapsto \ \phi|_W
$$
But I failed.

Comment: The question corresponds with exercise 1.9(d).

Answer (score 2):

You have the right idea: given $(\phi_W)_{W\in I}\in\varprojlim_{W\in I} S_W$, you have described how to define a function $\phi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{Z}$ by the formula $\phi(x)=\phi_{\{x\}}(x)$.  Now all you have to show is that $\phi$ is injective to get a contradiction.  The key point is that failure of injectivity can be detected by a finite set.  That is, if $\phi$ were not injective, there would be $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ with $x\neq y$ and $\phi(x)=\phi(y)$.  Now just consider $\phi_{\{x,y\}}$: we must have $$\phi_{\{x,y\}}(x)=\phi_{\{x\}}(x)=\phi(x)=\phi(y)=\phi_{\{y\}}(y)=\phi_{\{x,y\}}(y).$$  This contradicts the fact that $\phi_{\{x,y\}}$ must be injective.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I need more explanation for the first two sentences, the rest is clair. Why is it actually enough to show that the $\phi$ must be injective?

Comment: Because there doesn't exist any injection $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{Z}$.  You found such an injection by starting with an element of the inverse limit, so no such element can exist: the inverse limit must be empty.

Comment: The point I don't entirely understand as $\phi$ *is* an element of $\varprojlim S_W$. I don't precisely understand the identification of of $\varprojlim S_W$ with $\{ f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{Z} \ | \ f \text{ injective } \}$. That's what my question is about.

Comment: $\phi$ is not an element of $\varprojlim S_W$.  You took an element $(\phi_W)_{W\in I}\in \varprojlim S_W$, and defined from it a function $\phi$ by the formula $\phi(x)=\phi_{\{x\}}(x)$.

Comment: I got it, thank you so much. I would like you to point out that crucial subtlety in the beginning of your answer, because I first though that we had to do some identification between the limit and the injective maps $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{Z}$, but we *deduce* a map $\phi$ from an element $(\phi_W)_W$ from the limit. I would like that future readers are aware of that.

Comment: Dear @Eric Wofsey, did you read my previous comment? If you like I can edit your answer.